# WSL2 in Windows 10: sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I don't exactly know what I did wrong, but now every command that needs `sudo` returns:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I found a bunch of answers for fixing this in these situations:

- If I was running Linux and could boot with a live USB
- If I was running Mac OSx.

But I'm running WSL2 in Windows 10, so these answers didn't helped me.

Have I rendered my WSL useless? Is there a way to fix this windows-side?

Things I've tried in WSL terminal (Ubuntu 20):

```
pkexec chown root:root /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.d -R
pkexec visudo
```

Both gives me `Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory` response.

I've also tried `su - root`, but I put my password and it gives me `Authentication failure`.

Let's suppose this has no answer and I need to reset my Ubuntu WLS install. Is there a way to export everything that I did, installed and all, or will I have to start ALL over?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Whoa, @Terrance , this did it for me. I can't believe I didn't find this before. Want to answer below so I can mark it as right answer?